# Add space after three numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have my numbers in a format that is easier for the user to read.
Eg. Instead of: 12349568483, it would be: 12 349 568 483.
I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: Then it has to be a string, there are no spaces in numbers ?

Comment: `'2349568483'.replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1 ")` -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7Nmng/

Comment: yea, it would need to be a string, I just didn't know what code to use to add spaces to the specific spots. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = "12349568483";
a = a.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/([0-9]{3})/g, "$1 ").split('').reverse().join('');
```

Comment: The only reason this is more convoluted than the regular one is because it splits from the right rather than from left because they are numbers... ;)